# Splitting data 80/20 per class

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I'm seeking to have an equal distribution of my samples across various datasets when splitting my data in an 80/20 train/validation set. I do not want to do it at random because I need equal distribution of samples across both sets and avoid creating a bias. However, I want to make sure that for every class of label 80% of the samples are in the training set.

With this, I wanted to try and do this in the caret package for R, such as:

```
data_split <- createDataPartition(y=data$column, p=0.8, list=F) #splits data
training <- data[data_split,] #call training data
testing <- data[-data_split,] #call testing or validation data
```

e.g. I have 64 classes and was thinking of doing the random data parititon per class.

Would this be correct?

Comment: what distribution of classes do you get with the code you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly what you want, you are doing well. The `createDataPartition` function works exactly for this kind of situation. It performs a simple splitting based on the outcome as reported on the [vignette](http://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html#simple-splitting-based-on-the-outcome)

> the random sampling occurs within each class and should preserve the overall class distribution of the data

we can check if is true with a simple plot

```
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(5)
df <- 
data.frame(a=runif(1000),b=runif(1000)*10,c=sample(as.character(1:64),1000,replace = 
T))
str(df)
#split the data in 80/20 train/test
ind <- createDataPartition(df$c, p=0.8,list = F)
train <- df[ind,]
test <- df[-ind,]
#frequencies of each class for the whole dataset
x <- table(df$c)/length(df$c)
#for the training set
x_train <- table(train$c)/length(train$c)
#for the testing set
x_test<- table(test$c)/length(test$c)

freq <- data.frame(class=names(x),df=as.numeric(x),train=as.numeric(x_train),test=as.numeric(x_test))


ggplot(freq,aes(x=class))+
geom_line(aes(y=df,group=1),col="red")+
geom_line(aes(y=train,group=1),col="green")+
geom_line(aes(y=test,group=1),col="blue")+
ylab("frequencies")
```

[image]

As you can see the distribution of each class is preserved

Comment: Hey Elia, this definitely answers what I was looking for. Thanks for the amazing input and I've tested it and it definitely works :D